# Rails active record model method chaining and getting the initial input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, method-chaining

This feels like it should be very simple but am unsure the correct syntax.  This is me playing and learning, so this isn't pressing.

I would like to write a custom method on a model that performs an action and takes the input from the method chain instead of require you to set the input arguments in the method call.

Given that we have the following simple class;

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  scope :for_user, ->(u) { where(user_id: u.id) }

  def self.do_thing
    # How do I get the results from the chain?
    # For example how do I get the IDs?
  end
end
```

So I'd like to be able to do this;

```
Comments.for_user(current_user).do_thing
```

And have the `do_thing` method know what the results of `Comments.for_user(current_user)`

Now obviously I could make do_thing have method arguments and just go that route, but I'm playing and learning about method chaining..

Thanks for your input.

Comment: What's you've written would **already work**, no? What do you actually want `do_thing` to do? Try defining the method, and see if it works as you expect.

Comment: It's pretty hard to give advice on how to write the code, when the only information you've given us is a blank method with no desired behaviour :)

Comment: You're right.. sorry.. In do thing, how do I know and manipulate the input?  So the results from the first two are an active record relationship.. Let's say I want to get the ID's of the results only.

Comment: If it helps, you can think of `scope :for_user, ->(u) ...` being virtually the same thing as defining `def self.for_user(u) ...`

Comment: Make do thing just print out the IDs of the results that were sent to it.. for example.  Sorry I didn't give an example in the original post.. I'll edit it

Comment: The result of the previous method call would be `self`. If you want to get the `IDs`, then you can do `self.pluck(:id)`. But since `self` is always the implicit method receiver, you probably don't even need to mention it... You could just do `def do_thing; pluck(:id); end`

Comment: Like I said above: Why don't you try defining it, and see if it works? I would be surprised if your first attempt fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  scope :for_user, ->(u) { where(user_id: u.id) }

  def self.do_thing
    # How do I get the results from the chain?
    # For example how do I get the IDs?
    self.ids
  end
end
```

Use `self`. The way scopes work is that they return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that proxies method calls back to the model class.

Although in this case the method will actually break chaining since it returns an array and not self or an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.